# Function like ctype_alpha but with special letters

Tags: php

I used `ctype_alpha()` on a input so someone can't write numbers or special signs.

```
ctype_alpha($_POST["name"])
```

But i just noticed a problem today. This only check A-Z and not special letters like Å Ä Ö.

How should i structure this instead? So you can't write numbers and special signs but you can write special letters?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `/\P{L}/`: http://codepad.viper-7.com/HO7kBw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regexp that matches a [Unicode character class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php). For example, `\p{L}` to match letters:

```
if (preg_match('/^\p{L}*$/', $_POST['name'])) ...
```

Comment: I used it with "García" and return 0. But i guess we can alter the regex to make it work